# exporting a scene from blender to threejs: every object has just one single material

Tags: three.js, blender, exporter

I have made a small scene in blender (6 objects, each using 1 to 4 materials).
When exporting this (using the materials, and the scene option) with the dev exporter and loading it via:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( 'assets/scene.json', function ( scene ) { ...
```

And then checking the scene, I can see it has 6 children (good) and that each of the five children only has one MeshLambertMaterial (instead of the material mix from blender) bad.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Those are btw basic materials (just a color basically) no textures or anything.

The scene renders correctly (minus the material mix).

Here is a link to the 113kb scene file (zipped): http://jppresents.net/static/blender/exportBug/scene.zip

Looking at the file I think all materials are there - so the problem must be the way I load it?

Comment: you still having this issue?, i cant load your scene...anyways a snap shot image would do :)

Comment: Thank you for checking in. I could not figure out how to export more than one material per object, but I have fixed my problem by uv-mapping and using a texture. (instead of different materials with different colors I now use one material, uv mapped to different colors all on one texture.)

Comment: thats good then... , just answer your own question of how you went about fixing your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a work around:
Since the only difference between all my materials was just the color, I have now applied exactly one material with a multi colored texture per object.
Then I uv-mapped the faces of the object to the colors corresponding to the previously set material color.

This was easy using the hotkey "shift + G" which lets you select all faces with the same material. (Then just assign them to the texture material, move/scale those in the uv-view to the part of the texture that matches the old color.)